# What version of Visual studio 2010 to install for working with 64 bit sharepoint?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I would like to know if it becomes necessary to install a 64 bit version of visual studio 2010 when we are using sharepoint 2010, since sharepoint 2010 only installs in 64 bit systems.

Comment: good luck finding a 64 bit version of Visual Studio :)

Answer (score 5):

A 64 bit version of Visual Studio [does not exist](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/10/visual-studio-why-is-there-no-64-bit-version.aspx), so you will have to install the 32 bit version. You can create and debug 64 bit applications with the 32 bit version of Visual Studio.